# Encryption key input screen does not appear during boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, encryption, lvm, passphrase

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and enabled device encryption during installation. Previously, there came up a nice looking screen and asked for the passphrase for decrypting the drive. I tried to uninstall ghostwriter and executed the command `sudo apt autoremove`, then I rebooted and now the screen does not appear anymore.

Instead I get an empty purple screen, after approx. 5 seconds the screen color changes to black. Then nothing happens anymore. I then can switch via Ctrl+Alt+F2 and then Ctrl+Alt+F1 to the tty. Here I get a message to `failed to connect lvmetad`, but I am able to enter the passphrase here and unlock my drive to boot.

How can I repair or reinstall the required packages for the standard passphrase request screen?

EDIT: I am not sure if this might be related, but I also removed 'ghostscript' becuase I confused the apps in the terminal. And then I ran the autoremove. Afterwards I installed ghostscript again.

EDIT 2: It seems autoremove removed a lot of stuff. I was able to find out what packages were removed via:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep remove
```

And it showed me this list: 
[List of removed packages (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/raw/R1bX0Cbw)

EDIT3: After reinstalling ubuntu-desktop the screen is now back and everything looks fine...

I still will let this post here in case someone experiences the same or an comparable issue.

Comment: Please post a formal answer to your question for the benefit of others

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I removed a lot of packages without being aware of it. Since I accidentally removed the ghostscript package when I wanted to remove ghostewriter, and then executed `sudo apt autoremove`, autoremove removed a lot of packages which are depending on ghostscript.

To solve my problems I had to:

1. Find out which packages were removed via `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep remove`
2. Reinstall the package ubuntu-desktop which was removed

Afterwards, everything was back to normal.